# Prove that $f(w)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\partial\Bbb{D}}\frac{f(z)}{1-w\bar{z}}|dz|$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Let $f$ be analytic in an open set containing $\bar{\Bbb{D}}$. If $w\in \Bbb{D}$ then prove that $$f(w)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\partial\Bbb{D}}\frac{f(z)}{1-w\bar{z}}|dz|$$

First of all,since $\frac{1}{1-u}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}u^k$ for all $u\in \mathbb{D}$, I can let $u=w\bar{z}$ and we have $\frac{1}{1-w\bar{z}}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(w\bar{z})^k$. Also, since $f(z)$ analytic, it has a power series expansion $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$. If $w\in \mathbb{D}$ is fixed, then for any $z\in \mathbb{D}$, $\frac{1}{1-w\bar{z}}$ converges uniformly, as well as $f(z)$. Consequently, I can deduce that it's product $\frac{f(z)}{1-w\bar{z}}$ is uniformly convergent.

Can anyone help me finish the proof?

Comment: Is $\mathbb{D}$ the unit disk?

Comment: Yes it is. Sorry for not defining it.

Answer (score 1):

On $\partial \Bbb D$, $\bar{z} = z^{-1}$ and $|dz| = \dfrac{dz}{iz}$, making

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\partial \Bbb D} \frac{f(z)}{1 - w\bar{z}}\lvert dz\rvert = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\partial \Bbb D} \frac{f(z)}{1 - wz^{-1}} \frac{dz}{iz} = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial \Bbb D} \frac{f(z)}{z - w}\, dz$$
The last expression is equal to $f(w)$ by the Cauchy integral formula.

Comment: Hi Kobe.  It's good to see that you've returned!  (+1)

Comment: Thank you. Would you please explain how $\bar{z}=z^{-1}$ on $\partial \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @YaG it’s because $z\bar{z} = 1$ for $z$ on $\partial \Bbb  D$.

Comment: @kobe Then, how is $|dz|=\frac{dz}{iz}$? I tried to understand it as a parametrisation, but I cannot derive it.

Comment: @YaG if $z = e^{i\theta}$ then $dz = ie^{i\theta}\, d\theta = iz\, d\theta$. Now $|dz| = d\theta$ and thus $dz = iz\, |dz|$ or $|dz| = dz/(iz)$.